# How to link values between exact cells in excel?

Tags: excel, cells

I would like to make a dropdown list in one cell with linked values"

For example:We choose Ford in first cell and in next one appear certain value (Focus),we choose Honda in next cell appear Civic and so on

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, you need to maintain (say, in a hidden sheet) the lists of models for each brand.

After defining the lists, you need to create NAMED ranges for each list where the range starts at the first model of the brand and ends at the last (you can use excel worksheet functions like OFFSET to achieve that).

Once you have that, you need to perform two actions:

1. Find the needed column as a result of the user's selection (i.e. Ford, Mercedes, etc.); this can be done using VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP.
2. Sent the target cell into which the model is to be deployed as a LIST (using INPUT VALIDATION) where the list is in fact the named range that corresponds to the brand selection.

These are the guidelines. You will find plenty of examples in the Internet to properly use these functions.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the choose() function to select which list will be displayed with the drop down.
Cell D4 is a drop down for manufacturer. F4 drop down for model. The list is generated in cells G9 to 11 from whichever list via the choose function and the if in cell E9.

See this:
[image: example of choose, if and data validation]